# I am running into an error with an npm command in react. "ERROR in main Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, webpack

I have been following a django-react tutorial and ran into a problem with the command npm run dev. I thought it was a problem with the webpack file but maybe not.

```
[error message][1]
[webpack file][2]
[package.json][3]
[file structure and app.js][4]
[index.js][5]
```

This is the error that I am receiving:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCK8g.png
(django_venv) C:\Users\bostm\Documents\CodingProjects\React-Django
\music_controller\frontend>npm run dev

> frontend@1.0.0 dev
> webpack --mode development --watch

[webpack-cli] Compilation starting...
[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
asset main.js 0 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main)

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/index.js' in 'C:\Users\bostm
\Documents\CodingProjects\React-Django\music_controller\frontend'

webpack 5.10.2 compiled with 1 error in 136 ms
[webpack-cli] watching files for updates...
```

This is the webpack file. I assumed the problem was here because the error message said that it couldn't resolve **"./src/index.js"** in the path to the frontend directory, which is the name of the webapp folder that src/index is in. I tried using a solution from another post by using path.resolve(__dirname, /path/). It did not work so this is what I had originally.

```
[2]
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

This is the package.json file. The only lines I added were for "dev" and "build."

```
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yea1b.png
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.10.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

This is my app.js file The screenshot is included mostly so that you can see how the file directory is setup and I was not sure how to include that as text in the post itself.

```
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLBXd.png
```

Lastly the index.js file which is just a single line importing App from components.

```
[5]
import App from "./components/App";
```

Sorry if anything about my problem is unclear **let me know if I can clarify anything**. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm really not sure where I went wrong. I have been considering going back and just creating the react app using npx create-react-app [appName], but I would like to know how to set it up manually in case I want to use something other than babel and webpack in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: The error is in `main.js`; according to the screenshot, the path from there to index.js is `../src/index.js`. (you have a `frontend` folder inside a `frontend` folder, maybe by accident?, also, when you post about a tutorial, always provide a link so we can check your code against the tutorial)

Comment: This is the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6c2NqDyxppU&t=633s

This is the github: https://github.com/techwithtim/Music-Controller-Web-App-Tutorial
The second frontend folder inside static was intentional. I also tried changing the path to "../src/index.js" in the webpack file. Thank you